# Javascript timer desynchronizes

Tags: javascript, timer, vue.js

I'm writing a small game in Vue.js, like an incremental one and I'm having issues with my timer. The game is planned to be targeted to mobile via Cordova, when user switch applications or lock phone, the `timer.stop()` is triggered and is resumed when page get focus again.
I don't need the game to be refreshed a lot, once a second or 0.5/s is enough (hence the speed button).

Here's my issue: when I quickly pause and resume game, timer get out of hand and go faster until I pause and resume timer again. [Video link](https://www.opentest.co/share/4c9e13a0d1b611e688ecd510bcea4514) for better explanation.

The timer code :

```
const {EventEmitter} = require('events')

module.exports = class Game extends EventEmitter {
  constructor (options = {}) {
    super()

    this.framesPerSecond = options.framesPerSecond || 60
    this.maxFrameSkip = options.maxFrameSkip || 10
    this.waitTime = options.waitTime || 0

    this._nextTick = Date.now()
    this._lastTick = 0
    this._updateTicks = 0
    this._running = false
  }

  get isRunning () {
    return this._running
  }

  get updateTicks () {
    return this._updateTicks
  }

  get currentTick () {
    return this._updateTicks % this._framesPerSecond
  }

  set framesPerSecond (framesPerSecond) {
    this._framesPerSecond = framesPerSecond
    this._skipTicks = Math.floor(1000 / framesPerSecond)
  }

  get framesPerSecond () {
    return this._framesPerSecond
  }

  set maxFrameSkip (maxFrameSkip) {
    this._maxFrameSkip = maxFrameSkip
  }

  get maxFrameSkip () {
    return this._maxFrameSkip
  }

  set waitTime (waitTime) {
    this._waitTime = waitTime
  }

  get waitTime () {
    return this._waitTime
  }

  start () {
    this.emit('start')
    this._running = true
    this._lastTick = this._nextTick
    this._run()
  }

  stop () {
    this._running = false
    this.emit('stop')
  }

  _run () {
    const next = this._nextTick = Date.now()
    const max = this._updateTicks + this._maxFrameSkip
    const skip = this._skipTicks

    while (this._lastTick <= next && this._updateTicks < max) {
      this.emit('update')
      this._lastTick += skip
      this._updateTicks++
    }

    this._running && setTimeout(() => this._run(), this._waitTime)
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what could I improve ?

Comment: I guess `this._running && setTimeout(() => this._run(), this._waitTime)` will set timer and after certain amount of time it will call `() => this._run()` Reference of this timer should be cleared when you are calling stop function. something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: Seems to works ! Put your comment in answer so I can accept it, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running a timer you are calling _run after some time interval. While you are pausing a game, you are not clearing that timer. It can make _run function to run one more time while you are clicking button immediately. You can use [clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) as described below.

```
// while pausing the timer, clears old timer reference 
stop () {
    this._running = false
    this.emit('stop')
    if ( this._timer ) {
        clearTimeout(this._timer);
    }
}

_run () {
    // All your code related to game.

   // Here saving reference of timer in this._timer
   if ( this._running ) {
       this._timer = setTimeout(() => this._run(), this._waitTime)
   }
}
```